# How long to surpass Voyager satellite distances using modern technology?

Tags: nasa, voyager, deep-space, time, oort-cloud

NASA's JPL just recently acknowledged that [Voyager II has now joined Voyager I in entering interstellar space](https://www.npr.org/2018/12/10/675324587/voyager-2-bids-adieu-to-the-heliosphere-entering-interstellar-space) after 41 years of space travel. This got me to wondering: when will we ever get to Alpha Centauri (or some other interstellar object beyond the Oort cloud?

[This post](https://www.npr.org/2018/12/10/675324587/voyager-2-bids-adieu-to-the-heliosphere-entering-interstellar-space) quotes NASA:

> It will take about 300 years for Voyager 2 to reach the inner edge of the Oort Cloud... and possibly 30,000 years to fly beyond it.

**My question:**

Assuming that technology has greatly improved since 1977 when the Voyager satellites were launched, **how long would it take for a modern spacecraft to surpass the distance from the sun [achieved by the Voyager satellites](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/)?**

Comment: It's a good question, and so has been asked before.

Comment: @uhoh I figured it had been, but a quick search didn't pull it up for me. Glad someone found the dupe, since it has a well thought out answer to ponder over.